# Can a PCIe wireless network adapter be used as a full access point, and if so how

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have a TL-WDN4800 PCEe (450Mbps) on my desktop (originally to connect to WiFi when I was living in a different house), and I would like to make this into a wireless access point (I have no need for any router like features, just bridging to the ethernet adapter is fine).

The intent here is to get a faster access point than a Huawei HG533 router, and I only need to connect to it with a Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230 (300Mbps) downstairs.

The problem I am having is the TP-LINK software seems to have just a "Soft AP" option with no configuration (beyond which interface to "internet connecting share", ssid and password) which gives just a 52Mbps link even at near zero range and often has short bursts of poor connectivity (its picking channel 11, I guess 20MHz width, which conflicts with 2 other local hotspots I can see).

Is there some other way / software to configure this piece of hardware todo what I want, or do I need to buy something different?

Comment: SoftAP is pretty much what you want. It should generate an access point from the WiFi card.

If the link is weak, then you may need to invest in a bigger antenna and/or change the channel that the SoftAP is broadcasting on.

Comment: But it has no configuration, like even picking a non-congested channel (there is no 5GHz hotspots and several unused 2.4GHz channels are since a rural area, but its choice puts 3 networks on one channel...).

Comment: Is there any newer software / drivers for the card ?

Comment: I have the 2014/06/05 driver & utility from http://www.tp-link.com/lk/support/download/?model=TL-WDN4800&version=V1#tbl_a